# regular expression which accept alpha character or alphanumeric character or alpha character with special symbol

Tags: c#

Regular expression which accept alpha character or alphanumeric character or alpha character with special symbol or alphanumeric character with special symbol.It should not accept only number or only special character.

For eg:
Valid string:

```
abc
abc 1
abc-1
abc abc
```

Invalid string

```
111111
****
```

Comment: _Any_ effort so far to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming that "special symbol" means all non-alphanumberic characters

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).*$
```

otherwise replace `.` with `[0-9a-zA-Z-*]` and all the characters you want to be allowed